# Powershell script working with xml produces different output in PowerGUI and Powershell console

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a following script in PS:

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $Config;

function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
    Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}

function LoadConfig
{
    $configPath = Join-Path (Get-ScriptDirectory) Config.xml    
    $Config = [xml](gc $configPath) 
}

function WriteData
{
    $sourceFolderPath = $Config.Deploy.SourceFolder
    Write-Host $sourceFolderPath   
}

LoadConfig
WriteData
```

My basic xml file looks like:

```
<Deploy>
    <SourceFolder>C:\FolderPath</SourceFolder>
<Deploy>
```

When I debuging it in PowerGUI tool it works fine and it writes the correct output. But when I run the same script in powershell console in Windows 7, the result is empty line. I have no idea why.

Comment: Is `$configPath` always the same?

Comment: yes it is. Meanwhile I have solved it. See answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script has a trouble, as you declare `[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $Config` at the begining of your script, you have to use `$global:Config` in `LoadConfig` function. For more explanations have look to `Get-Help about_Scopes`.

```
function LoadConfig 
{ 
    $configPath = Join-Path (Get-ScriptDirectory) Config.xml     
    $global:Config = [xml](gc $configPath)  
}
```

Why does it work in PowerGui ? Because `$config` exist in your session, you'd better configure PowerGui like I show in the following picture.

[image]